# Showing Material Dialog, No MaterialLocalizations found

Tags: flutter, dialog

I tried to make Dialog function on my app.
But the "No MaterialLocalizations found." error came out and it didn't open the popup window.
I don't know how to solve this issue even though I tried to find other references.
Please let me know how to fix this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(OverApp());
}

class OverApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OverAppState createState() => _OverAppState();
}

class _OverAppState extends State<OverApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('List'),
        ),
        body: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Show Material Dialog'),
          onPressed: _showMaterialDialog,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _showMaterialDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text("Material Dialog"),
          content: new Text("Hey!"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('Close me!'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `MaterialApp` in `runApp` (or make another widget and put the `Scaffold` in its build and use this new widget as the home of the `MaterialApp`).

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: OverApp()));
}

class OverApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OverAppState createState() => _OverAppState();
}

class _OverAppState extends State<OverApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Show Material Dialog'),
        onPressed: _showMaterialDialog,
      ),
    );
  }

  _showMaterialDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
              title: new Text("Material Dialog"),
              content: new Text("Hey!"),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Close me!'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works well. But I have a question that why I should put MaterialApp in runApp even though I already added this in Build widget. And also you commented the another way. Could you let me know how to do that please? Thank you!!!

Comment: Happy to help! The reason behind this error is that the context in the root (where the `MaterialApp` is) is not the context that should be used to show the dialog, so it is a wrong context. By putting the `MaterialApp` outside, or making another widget, the context that is passed to the `showDialog` will be correct. @김동현